# Why does `collect` make the observer received no notifications?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-scala

I'm using rxscala and found a very subtle problem, and my code is simplied to the following:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable
import rx.lang.scala.subjects.PublishSubject

object SubtleBug extends App {

  case class Projects(projects: List[Project] = Nil)
  case class Project(name: String, docs: List[Doc] = Nil)
  case class Doc(path: String, baseContent: String)

  sealed trait ServerEvent
  case class ProjectNames(projects: Seq[String]) extends ServerEvent
  case class NewDocument(projectName: String, path: String, version: Int, content: String) extends ServerEvent

  val receivedEvents = PublishSubject[ServerEvent]

  new Thread(new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      val events = Seq(
        new ProjectNames(Seq("p1", "p2")),
        NewDocument("p1", "/aaa", 1, "my-content"),
        NewDocument("p1", "/bbb", 1, "my-content")
      )
      events.foreach { event =>
        receivedEvents.onNext(event)
        Thread.sleep(200)
      }
    }
  }).start()

  lazy val projects: Observable[Option[Projects]] = receivedEvents.scan(Option.empty[Projects]) {
    case (_, ProjectNames(names)) => {
      Some(Projects(names.map(name => Project(name)).toList))
    }
    case (Some(ps), NewDocument(projectName, docPath, version, content)) => {
      val doc = Doc(docPath, content)
      val newPs = ps.copy(projects = ps.projects.map {
        case project if project.name == projectName => project.copy(docs = project.docs ::: List(doc))
        case p => p
      })
      Some(newPs)
    }
    case _ => None
  }.collect({
    case Some(p) => Some(p)
  })

  projects.foreach(ps => {
    println("### 111: " + ps.map(_.projects))
    projects.foreach(x => println("### 222: " + ps.map(_.projects))) // !!!(2)
  })

  Thread.sleep(2000)

}
```

The key point is the `!!!(2)` line, which is inside the `projects` itself.

It prints the following:

```
### 111: Some(List(Project(p1,List()), Project(p2,List())))
### 111: Some(List(Project(p1,List(Doc(/aaa,my-content))), Project(p2,List())))
### 111: Some(List(Project(p1,List(Doc(/aaa,my-content), Doc(/bbb,my-content))), Project(p2,List())))
```

The problem is there is no `### 222:` lines!

But if I change the `collect` part, and adding the `None` case:

```
.collect({
  case Some(p) => Some(p)
  case None => None // added case
})
```

It will print the `### 222:` lines as I expected:

```
### 111: None
### 111: Some(List(Project(p1,List()), Project(p2,List())))
### 111: Some(List(Project(p1,List(Doc(/aaa,my-content))), Project(p2,List())))
### 222: None
### 222: None
### 222: Some(List(Project(p1,List()), Project(p2,List())))
### 222: Some(List(Project(p1,List()), Project(p2,List())))
### 111: Some(List(Project(p1,List(Doc(/aaa,my-content), Doc(/bbb,my-content))), Project(p2,List())))
### 222: None
### 222: Some(List(Project(p1,List()), Project(p2,List())))
### 222: Some(List(Project(p1,List(Doc(/aaa,my-content))), Project(p2,List())))
### 222: Some(List(Project(p1,List(Doc(/aaa,my-content))), Project(p2,List())))
```

I can't understand why.

PS: You can clone the code here: https://github.com/freewind/rxscala-test/blob/master/src/main/scala/myrx/SubtleBug.scala

Answer (score 0):

There is a race condition in your codes. `PublishSubject` will drop any events before you subscribe it. So if `receivedEvents.onNext(event)` runs before `projects.foreach`, event will be dropped. And in `scan`, if the first event is dropped, the pattern match won't work any more.

You can use `ReplaySubject` to fix it.

Comment: That's strange, I just tried the code and it will output the `### 111: Some(...` lines as in my question. You might miss the method [receivedEvents.scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html), which is like `foldLeft`, so I can passing a `Option.empty[Projects]` as match with it